# Wordpress - redirect editpage link to another page

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to redirect /wp-admin/post.php?post=1475&action=edit
to /web-team-stuff/whoa-there

I'm using the quick redirect plugin, but the redirect rule is being ignored. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Quick Redirect only works for URLs outside the admin area. The URL you listed as the redirect-from address: `/wp-admin/post.php?post=1475&action=edit` is handled by Wordpress upstream of the plugin.

If you're trying to redirect a specific post, use the post's permalink as the redirect-from address.